# Why does the main View Controller not unload when the app is open

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I know that the main (first) view controller does not unload until the app is quit on iOS but my question is why?  I believe that you know how to use something better when you know why it is done like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first view controller which you typically add to the main window of your app is typically initialized in the application delegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, ie. at app startup.  It is the foundation unto which all other ui components are added.  It is always present.  If it were to unload before the app is quit then the app would no longer have a ui.